# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, React app error when trying to save a playlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can't seem to resolve this error.

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQcxv.png)

For the function to work the user is supposed to be able to add songs to a 'New Playlist' and then save that playlist.

The app seems to work fine until you click the button to save the playlist at which point all you see is this error.

Trying to access this component:

```
const clientId = "783dbc97776940e28f307dfc902ad41b";
const redirectUri = "http//localhost:3000/";
let accessToken;

const Spotify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    }

    // check for access token match
    const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

    if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
      const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
      // This clears the parameters, allowing us to grab a new access token when it expires.
      window.setTimeout(() => (accessToken = ""), expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState("Access Token", null, "/");
      return accessToken;
    } else {
      const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
      window.location = accessUrl;
    }
  },

  search(term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(jsonResponse => {
        if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
          return [];
        }
        return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          artist: track.artists[0].name,
          album: track.album.name,
          uri: track.uri
        }));
      });
  },

  savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
    if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
      return;
    }

    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    let userId;

    return fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", { headers: headers })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonResponse => {
        userId = jsonResponse.id;
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
          headers: headers,
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ name: name })
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(jsonResponse => {
            const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(
              `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`,
              {
                headers: headers,
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({ uris: trackUris })
              }
            );
          });
      });
  }
};

export default Spotify;
```

For use here:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';

import Spotify from '../../util/Spotify';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchResults: [],
      playlistName: 'My Playlist',
      playlistTracks: []
    }
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
    this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
    this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  addTrack(track) {
    if (this.state.playlistTracks.find(savedTrack => savedTrack.id === track.id)) {
      return;
    }

    this.state.playlistTracks.push(track);
    this.setState({playlistTracks: this.state.playlistTracks})
  }

  removeTrack(track) {
    this.setState.playlistTracks = this.state.playlistTracks.filter(currentTrack => currentTrack.id !== track.id)

    this.setState({playlistTracks: this.state.playlistTracks})
  }

  updatePlaylistName(name) {
    this.setState({playlistName: name});
  }

  savePlaylist() {
    const trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map(track => track.uri);
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        playlistName: 'New Playlist',
        playlistTracks: []
      })
    })
  }

  search(term) {
    Spotify.search(term).then(searchResults => {
      this.setState({searchResults: searchResults})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onAdd={this.addTrack} />
            <Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName} playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks} onRemove={this.removeTrack} onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName} onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// if(typeof(App.savePlaylist) == 'undefined') {
//   console.log('whoops')
// }

export default App;
```

Any ideas why?
I'm very new to this and am completely lost as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Promise for when the input is not right:

```
if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

Also, don't change variables of the state object. Don't do this:

```
this.state.playlistTracks.push(track);
this.setState({playlistTracks: this.state.playlistTracks})
```

Instead, do this:

```
this.setState({playlistTracks: [...this.state.playlistTracks, track]})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that fixed it. Only, now there aren't any songs showing up when I enter search. Any ideas from what I've posted or should I make another post?

Answer (score 1):

In you code when the following `if` condition is true, you're not returning a promise.

```js
savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
    if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
      return;
      // What you can do instead
      // return Promise.reject();
    };
....
...
```

Simply returning `return;` will return `undefined` and trying to access `then` on it will throw error.